# Beamer: Transparent cover previous and following items

Tags: beamer, transparency

The LaTeX Beamer class offers a transparent overlay (`\setbeamercovered{transparent}`) which makes the following items a bit transparent. The items that were already shown stay at full opacity. In order to focus the listener's attention on the current item, I would prefer to have both the following and the already discussed items made transparent and only the current point displayed with full opacity.

---

Slide 1

```
- Foo
- Bar (opacity: 0.5)
- Ham (opacity: 0.5)
- Eggs (opacity: 0.5)
```

Slide 2

```
- Foo (opacity: 0.5)
- Bar
- Ham (opacity: 0.5)
- Eggs (opacity: 0.5)
```

Slide 3

```
- Foo (opacity: 0.5)
- Bar (opacity: 0.5)
- Ham
- Eggs (opacity: 0.5)
```

Slide 4

```
- Foo (opacity: 0.5)
- Bar (opacity: 0.5)
- Ham (opacity: 0.5)
- Eggs
```

---

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can highlight the current item only with `[<+>]`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+>]
\item Duck
\item Marmot
\item Sloth
\item Bear
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

---

And a little experiment just for fun:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{tikzducks,tikzlings}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+>]
\item \alt<.>{\tikz[scale=0.2]{\duck}}{Duck}
\item \alt<.>{\tikz[scale=0.2]{\marmot}}{Marmot}
\item \alt<.>{\tikz[scale=0.2]{\sloth}}{Sloth}
\item \alt<.>{\tikz[scale=0.2]{\bear}}{Bear}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ha Ha  the Dr. Zeus eggs and ham changed before my eyes into ducks and marmots

Comment: :) shall I replace the marmot with the tikzpig, so that eggs and ham transform to duck and pig?

Comment: :-) I was intrigued if you can over write a word with an include \tikzling at the time of itemize ?

Comment: something like you did here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424011/change-beamer-itemize-symbol-and-overlay?rq=1

Comment: @KJO That's just  proof of concept, I'm sure this can be further automated :)

Comment: How to highlight the current item, make all previous transparent and hide all the next ones?

Comment: @Sigur `\setbeamercovered{
  still covered={\opaqueness<1->{0}},
  again covered={\opaqueness<1->{15}}
}`

Comment: Perfect!! So pretty.