# Interleaving images in paused lists with Beamer

Tags: beamer, xetex, presentations

I have the following frame in my Beamer code:

```latex
\begin{frame}{Motivation}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> We deal with a lot of cameras.
        \item<1-> We do lots of experiments.
        \item<2-> How to multiplex the video streams?
        \item<3-> How to unify the API for controlling distinct cameras?
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

This works great as a "paused list" where each item ends up as a slide. I want, however, to interleave full-size images, but I'm not sure how to do it. What I mean by that is between each item there is a slide that's some figure from `\includegraphics`.

I tried making copies frames, but the positioning ends up wrong, and also tried to place the image within the item list, but that also ended up weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possibilities to accomplish this, this is a very basic one:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Motivation}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-2,4,6-> We deal with a lot of cameras.
        \item<1-2,4,6-> We do lots of experiments.
        \item<4,6-> How to multiplex the video streams?
        \item<6-> How to unify the API for controlling distinct cameras?
    \end{itemize}
\centering\vspace*{-2cm}%
\only<3>{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}\only<5>{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}
\vfill  
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are willing to load `tikz`, things become more elegant and straightforward.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Motivation}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> We deal with a lot of cameras.
        \item<1-> We do lots of experiments.
        \item<4-> How to multiplex the video streams?
        \item<6-> How to unify the API for controlling distinct cameras?
    \end{itemize}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \node[visible on=<3>,anchor=south] at ([yshift=3mm]current page.south)
 {\includegraphics[height=8cm]{example-image-a}};
 \node[visible on=<5>,anchor=south] at ([yshift=3mm]current page.south)
 {\includegraphics[height=8cm]{example-image-b}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Love the `tikz` solution! Thank you kind mammal!

Comment: The only issue I notice for the tikz way, @marmot, is that the page number overlays the image! Very hard to notice with my theme and image though :)

Comment: @BernardoMeurer In the animation I can't see it. You could either move the pics up a bit (assuming the page number is on the bottom) by increasing `[yshift=3mm]`. Or you need to add your preamble such that one could see why this happens (IMHO it should not).

Comment: it was something sketchy, because it only happened on one slide, the other one was fine. I moved the image up a bit, and it looks perfect. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

From a tikz [proof of concept](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/480256/170109) as discussed with Sam Carter but adapted to images however they are here a max 66%

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Motivation}
\begin{itemize}[<+>]
\item \alt<.>{We will now look at the following four images}{Start}
\item \alt<.>{\includegraphics[scale=0.66]{example-image}\\ We deal with a lot of cameras.}{Cameras}
\item \alt<.>{\includegraphics[scale=0.66]{example-image-a}\\ We do lots of experiments.}{Experiments}
\item \alt<.>{\includegraphics[scale=0.66]{example-image-b}\\ How to multiplex the video streams?}{Multiplex}
\item \alt<.>{\includegraphics[scale=0.66]{example-image-c}\\ How to unify the API for controlling distinct cameras?}{API Control}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```